# Stack overflow в рекурсивной функции

Tags: c++, visual-studio, рекурсия

По ходу выполнения программы возникает исключение "Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x79E917D7 (ucrtbased.dll) в ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x008A2FB8)."Вопрос с виду довольно тупой, но не могу додуматься.

```
    // Для заданного числа x распечатать числовую последовательность:
//sin(x), sin(sin(x)), sin(sin(sin(x))), …
//Вычисления прекратить, когда очередной элемент последовательности станет по
//модулю меньше, чем 10^-2 .


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float sinus(float x);



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    float x;
    cout << "Введите x >> ";
    while (!(cin >> x) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))//Цикл который очищает оставшиеся символы в потоке
    {
        cin.clear();//сброс битов ошибок входного стандартного потока
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "Неправильний ввід, будь ласка, повторіть ввід спочатку : " << endl;
    }
    sinus(x);
}
float sinus(float x) {
    float result;
    result = sin(x);
    cout << result << endl;
    if (abs(result) > 0.01) {
        sinus(result);

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ну и какая у вас глубина рекурсии? что тут непонятного?...

Comment: `sinus(result);` А почему вы не используете результат?

Comment: Это медленно убывающая последовательность. Замените рекурсию на цикл.

Comment: @ヒミコ Это в данном случае неважно.

Comment: @Igor спасибо, помогло, но все же интересно , в чем суть моей проблемы была ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это медленно убывающая последовательность. Замените рекурсию на цикл.

Память, выделенная на стек, ограничена. Так как последовательность убывает медленно, требуется большое количество вложенных вызовов функции `sinus`. Каждый вызов использует дополнительный кусочек стека. В какой-то момент место в стеке заканчивается.